# Excel VBA For Each skipping cells

Tags: vba, excel

Im coding a simple macro in excel vba that deletes an entire row if the first cell has an specific text. 
Here's the code so far:

```
Sub MyMacro()
    For Each MyCell In Worksheets("Hoja2").Range("A1:A20")
        If MyCell.Value = "BORRAR" Then
            MyCell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

My Sheet2 (Hoja2) just has two columns, the first column is full of "BORRAR" from A1 to A20 and the second column has only numbers, from 1 to 20.

If i activate the macro, it deletes every row except 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18 and 20.
If i activate the macro again, it deletes everything except 4,8,12,16,20
If i activate the macro again, it deletes everything except 8,16
And so on.

Why is this happening? As far as i understand, my macro checks one by one if the cell of the first column has the word "BORRAR" in it, and if it does, it deletes the entire row. Why deleting by multiple of 2,4,8...?

Comment: answer is in question itself

Comment: As you're deleting rows, you'll need to got backwards through the rows. Try a loop like `For i = lastrow to 2 Step -1`

Comment: that means next row occupied the deleted row. but the index is moved by one that get next next rows cell internally in core

Comment: performance wise this is good from ms. developer wise this is not good.

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're stepping forward through the rows and deleting them.

If you delete row 2 then row 3 becomes the new row 2 and the loop goes on to look at row 3 which is actually row 4 - row 3 has been missed completely.

Use:

```
For x = 20 to 1 Step -1
     If Worksheets("Hoja2").Cells(x,1) = "BORRAR" then
        Worksheets("Hoja2").Cells(x,1).EntireRow.Delete
     End IF
Next x
```

Note - I haven't tested the above code, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

that means that next row occupie's the deleted row. but the index is moved by one that gets next next rows cell internally in core

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the issue is that the for each loop detects how many elements it has to loop through. Then it starts the operation for the first, second, third etc. element. When you delete the first element, then the second element becomes the first element, but the loop continues it's job with the new second element. You can try if it works better when you're using `Range("A20:A1")`. If that still doesn't work, you'll have to use a `For To` or a `While` loop.